# Struct fields are not accessible

Tags: struct, rust, field

I'm trying to access different fields of a struct, but I get the following errors:

```
error[E0609]: no field `x` on type `Point`
 --> src/lib.rs:9:31
  |
8 |     fn distance<Point>(point1: &Point, point2: &Point) -> f64 {
  |                 ----- type parameter 'Point' declared here
9 |         let diffX = (*point1).x - (*point2).x;
  |                               ^
```

for x, y and z:

```rust
pub struct Point {
    pub x: f64,
    pub y: f64,
    pub z: f64,
}

impl Point {
    fn distance<Point>(point1: &Point, point2: &Point) -> f64 {
        let diffX = (*point1).x - (*point2).x;
        let diffY = (*point1).y - (*point2).y;
        let diffZ = (*point1).z - (*point2).z;
        (diffX * diffX + diffY * diffY + diffZ * diffZ).sqrt()
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `<Point>` introduces a generic type that shadows the `Point` struct.

Comment: https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=686fc1e418283974c6aec4feaa921736

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```rust
error[E0609]: no field `x` on type `Point`
 --> src/lib.rs:9:31
  |
8 |     fn distance<Point>(point1: &Point, point2: &Point) -> f64 {
  |                 ----- type parameter 'Point' declared here
9 |         let diffX = (*point1).x - (*point2).x;
  |                               ^
```

The error message shows that `Point` is a `type parameter` declared in line 8, which shadows the original `Point` type declared previously.

So the solution is to change this generic type to another name or just remove it cause I don't find any usage of it in the function body.

```rust
pub struct Point {
    pub x: f64,
    pub y: f64,
    pub z: f64,
}

impl Point {
    fn distance(point1: &Point, point2: &Point) -> f64 {
        let diffX = (*point1).x - (*point2).x;
        let diffY = (*point1).y - (*point2).y;
        let diffZ = (*point1).z - (*point2).z;
        (diffX * diffX + diffY * diffY + diffZ * diffZ).sqrt()
    }
}
```